Do relational projections modify attributes?
Wikipedia gives a formal definition of a projection in relational algebra:

$$\Pi_{a_1, \ldots, a_n} = \{ t [a_1, \ldots, a_n]: t \in R \}$$
where $t [a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ is the restriction of the tuple $t$ to the set $\{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$ so that
$$t [a_1, \ldots, a_n] = \{ (a^{\prime}, v) \mid (a^{\prime}, v) \in t, a^{\prime} \in \{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}\}$$ where $(a^{\prime}, v)$ is an attribute value, $a^{\prime}$ is > an attribute name, and $v$ is an element of that attribute's domain.

That definition makes sense to me, but then I noticed that earlier in the page it says this:

Projections may also modify attribute values. For example, if $R$ has attributes $a,b,c$ where the values of $b$ are numbers, then $\Pi_{a, b \times 0.5, c}(R)$ is like $R$, but with all $b$-values halved.

Wikipedia cites this claim and provides a link, but my firewall is blocking the link they provide.
My interpretation of the formal definition is that scaling elements is not included, but that seems to contradict the example with scaling. Is this just Wikipedia being inconsistent, or have I missed something?

Right, in the "generalised" version you'd have $(a', f(v))$ instead of $(a', v)$.
